# Store new position of RecyclerView items in SQLite after being dragged and dropped

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I have a two dimensional `ArrayList` of type `String` which is the input to the adapter class of the `RecyclerView`. The data in the list is taken from an SQLite database everytime when `onResume()` is called. I have implemented a drag and drop feature and an `onMove()` function that swaps the list elements successfully. However, I need to store the modified list before `onResume()` is called which will rewrite the list and fill it with old positions. My guess is to implement the rewriting functionality within the `onStop()` event. This is my main activity:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    assert fab != null;
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewDbActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();

    ItemTouchHelper item = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {

        @Override
        public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
            int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT;
            return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            Collections.swap(data, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
            adapter.notifyItemMoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMoved(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int fromPos, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target, int toPos, int x, int y) {
            super.onMoved(recyclerView, viewHolder, fromPos, target, toPos, x, y);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Moved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            data.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });

    item.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    initialize();

    if(adapter == null) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Adapter = NULL. Initialized");
        setAdapter();
    }
    else {
        Log.v(TAG, "notify is called");
        adapter.updateData(data);
    }
}

public void initialize() {
    Database ourDB = new Database(this);
    ourDB.openDB();
    data = ourDB.getData();
    ourDB.closeDB();
}

public void setAdapter() {
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(data, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

It is important to update the database as long as I know when to store the data. How can I solve this problem? Any suggestions?

!!!

**ANSWER:**

Final solution I have implemented:

```
@Override
public void onMoved(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int fromPos, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target, int toPos, int x, int y) {
    super.onMoved(recyclerView, viewHolder, fromPos, target, toPos, x, y);

    //preparing new position values
    long movedItem = Long.parseLong(data.get(fromPos).get(0));     // .get(fromPos).get(0) returns PRIMARY KEY from the list
    long draggedItem = Long.parseLong(data.get(toPos).get(0));

    // updating affected rows with new orders
    Database db = new Database(MainActivity.this);
        db.open();
        db.updateOrder(draggedItem, toPos);
        db.updateOrder(movedItem, fromPos);
        db.close();
}
```

And inside of DB class:

```
public void updateOrder(long rowID, int newPos) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_ORDER, newPos);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowID, null);
}
```

Comment: I have a same question(My newest question) I did try this . But I have an error . What is a KEY_ROWID . Can you explain KEY_ROWID

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a field in each DB row for storing the order.
Then you need to implements those features:

- On new row insert (when you insert a new object in database) you need to set the *order* field to the next int. You can get the current max value (with sql function `MAX`) and then simply do +1
- When user move an item in `RecyclerView`, in method `onMoved`you must update all other rows. You can use the `fromPos` and `toPos` for that. More on that below
- When you fill your `RecyclerView` with data you need to order them by `order` field

---

Explanation of 2nd feature to be implemented:
basically you need to update all rows with order between `fromPos` and `toPos`:

- if user moved the item up (for example from position 4 to 2), you need to:

  1. get primary key field of current item (using position 4)
  2. change all rows between order *2* and order *4*: so change 2 -> 3 and 3 -> 4
  3. Change current item order (using primary key of first point) to `toPos`: in this example change current item order to 2
- if user moved the item down (for example from position 2 to 4) you need to:

  1. get primary key field of current item (using position 2)
  2. change all rows between order 2 and order 4: so change 4 -> 3 and 3 -> 2
  3. change current item order (using primary key of first point) to `toPos`: in this example change current item order to 4

Hope it helps a little

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's my fault I forgot to mention that I have a separate column for storing the order and, as you've said, when I create new item I increment the max line. I had the same idea as you have offered, but I'm concerned about performance of app. Because `onMoved` is called everytime the list items are swapped. If user drags items very fast it may result in app being frozen. What do you think about that?

Comment: So you just need to implements 2nd point of the list. You can either add methods in database class (for example `moveOrderUp(int from, int to)` and `moveOrderDown(int from, int to)` or do it directly in your `onMoved` method. For me, the first approach is better

Comment: My second idea was to use the ArrayList<> which is already storing fresh data. As you can see `onMove` swaps the moved items there. Now I thought that maybe I could try to delete all data from DB, sort list object and upload it to DB again. But I don't know where to implement that and how it will affect on performance. But for now your solution to simply rewrite affected rows in DB and sort it at start

Comment: Well, deleting and re-inserting all data to db every time a row is moved is a (really) bad idea. With my idea you update only the rows that actually need to be updated. I don't know how to use that idea with your ArrayList

Comment: Sorry, but I meant to make these operations after all item movements are done. For instance, in `onStop` :) sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok then. But how to get the row which corresponds to the dragged item?

Comment: I understand now, sorry for that. You can get the current dragged item in the `onMoved` method. Just search it in arraylist using the `fromPos` parameter (it's equal to the current item order in ArrayList)

Comment: Thanks! I will try this idea soon

Comment: @Marat Have you got the answer this because I am trying the same I need to save the new position at the `SQLite`.
If you have done this please can you share code.

Comment: @rsella I am trying the same changing the position of recyclerview with onItemMoved but it doesn't save at the `SQLite`

Comment: @rsella I have written code for this but it did not work properly. Please check and help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665019/android-sorting-recycleview-item-on-drop-not-working-properly