# Save new positions in Room after recyclerView drag & drop

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I've implemented a recyclerView with a drag and drop feature in my app. Everything works fine until the app is relaunched --any drag and drop changes were not saved/remembered by the app.

I've tried:

- Using SharedPreference + GSON
- Reading other SQLite answers here on SO like this one: [Store new position of RecyclerView items in SQLite after being dragged and dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223107/store-new-position-of-recyclerview-items-in-sqlite-after-being-dragged-and-dropp)
- Reading [Paul Burke's Medium Post](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf)

My current code looks like this:

**In onCreate**

```
 ItemViewModel itemViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ItemViewModel.class);
    itemViewModel.getAllItems().observe(this, new Observer<List<Item>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Item> items) {

         adapter.setItemList(items);
         itemList = items; //Global variable itemList


        }
    });
```

**The method called when item is dragged/moved**

```
private void swap(int firstPosition, int secondPosition) {
    Collections.swap(itemList, firstPosition, secondPosition);
        for(int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
            Item currentItem = itemList.get(i);
            ItemViewModel.update(currentItem );
        }
        adapter.notifyItemMoved(firstPosition, secondPosition);
     }
```

Any ideas how I can let my app save the reordered recyclerView after drag and drop? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your entity have an `order` property in it ? If it does, you could access your dao and run an `UPDATE` SQL in the `Collections.swap` method when reordering and than on every load of the list, return the items ordered by that property.

Comment: @Igor It doesn't, though I did include an `.update(currentItem)` to update each item --somehow this doesn't work

Comment: If you wish to preserve the order of your items once you close your app or move to another activity, you will need to add a property to your entity files which will server as an order value for it. Since I don't think there is any other way of keeping that order after the app closes

Comment: @Igor Thanks for your suggestion. I was able to make it save according to what you said. If you want, please reply as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: @LittleNobody Please can you show or contact me because I am looking for the same answer I have added a question at SO.
I am chaning the positions with swap but it is not saving to the `SQLite`.
Below is my question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867970/changing-position-of-recyclerview-is-not-saving-at-sqlite-db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to preserve the order of your items once you close your app or move to another activity, you will need to add a property to your entity files which will server as an order value for it. Once added, you could access your dao and run an `UPDATE` SQL in the `Collections.swap` method when reordering items and than on every load of the list, return the items ordered by that property.

Comment: I have a question I am able to change the position but when I exit the app or go to another activity they are backed to the actual position.
Data are saved with `SQLite`.