# Collections.swap changes the position of the RecyclerView but it doesn't show anymore at Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I am trying to change the position of the `RecyclerView` this take changes but if I go to another `Activity` or exit the app and again open it, it tells me the right position.

The data are saved to an DB `SDQLite` and with `Adapter` I read from there and show to a `Fragment`.

`onMove` I have write a `Log` and it says the correct which position was and which is new.

At the `Log` the `arrayList = getSampleData()` it is working it saves always the position and read the actual position but the `ArrayList` at `Fragment` now is hidden it doesn't show me anything.
At the first time it shows normally all items but when I change position then items are hidden and if I make `arrayList.add(customer)` then shows me the data but are not sorted.

I use `Collections.swap` for changing positions.
Here is the video so you can see what is happening.
https://streamable.com/fdyyy

Below is my code.

`Fragment.class`

```
public class SpeedDialFragment extends Fragment  {
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    AdapterForBookmark myAdapter;
    List<Bookmark> test;
    View paramView;
    RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    BookmarkDB mDB;
    private Context mContext;
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
    public static final String LIST_OF_SORTED_DATA_ID = "json_list_sorted_data_id";
    public final static String PREFERENCE_FILE = "preference_file";
    private ItemTouchHelper mItemTouchHelper;
    public OnCustomerListChangedListener mListChangedListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
        mDB = new BookmarkDB(mContext);
        mDB.getAllBookmarks();
        buildBookmarkArrayListfromDB();
        loadBookMarksFromXML();
    }

    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        paramView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark, container, false);
        myRecyclerView = paramView.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myAdapter = new AdapterForBookmark(mContext, arrayList);

        final Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
        mSharedPreferences = getActivity()
                .getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        // arrayList.add(bookmark);
        arrayList = getSampleData();

        mListChangedListener = new OnCustomerListChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNoteListChanged(ArrayList<Bookmark> bookmarkList) {
                ArrayList<String> listOfSortedCustomerId = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (Bookmark customer: arrayList){
                    listOfSortedCustomerId.add(customer.getId());
                }

                // convert the List of Longs to a JSON string
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String jsonListOfSortedCustomerIds = gson.toJson(listOfSortedCustomerId);


                // save to SharedPreference
                mEditor.putString(LIST_OF_SORTED_DATA_ID, jsonListOfSortedCustomerIds).apply();
                mEditor.apply();
            }
        };
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        Log.d("TAG", "onCreateView: " + getSampleData());

        ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, 0) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
                int position_dragged = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                int position_target = viewHolder1.getAdapterPosition();
                long id = viewHolder.getItemId();
                Collections.swap(arrayList, position_dragged, position_target);
                myAdapter.notifyItemMoved(position_dragged, position_target);
                mListChangedListener.onNoteListChanged(arrayList);
                mDB.updateOrder(id, position_target);
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("OrderItems", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("item_positon", position_target);
                editor.apply();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSelectedChanged(@Nullable RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
                if (actionState != ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE) {
                    assert viewHolder != null;
                    viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30000000"));
                }
                super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);
            }

            @Override
            public void clearView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
                viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
            }

        });

        helper.attachToRecyclerView(myRecyclerView);
        return paramView;
    }


    private void loadBookMarksFromXML() {

        // MAY WISH TO ONLY DO THIS ONCE as bookmarks would be loaded OTHERWISE DELETE LINE BELOW
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB.getWritableDatabase(), BookmarkDB.TBL_BOOKMARK) > 0)
            return;
        try {
            XmlResourceParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.bookmarks);
            while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("Bookmark")) {
                        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
                        bookmark.setName(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                        bookmark.setSearchUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "searchUrl"));
                        bookmark.setNativeUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "nativeUrl"));
                        bookmark.setId(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "id"));
                        int drawableResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "icon"), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
                        bookmark.setIcon(drawableResourceId);
                        bookmark.setViewType(0);

                    }
                }
                xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void buildBookmarkArrayListfromDB() {
        arrayList.clear();
        arrayList.addAll(mDB.getAllBookmarks());
      /*  Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
        bookmark.setViewType(1);
        arrayList.add(bookmark);*/
    }
    private ArrayList<Bookmark> getSampleData(){

        //Get the sample data
        ArrayList<Bookmark> customerList = arrayList;

        //create an empty array to hold the list of sorted Customers
        ArrayList<Bookmark> sortedCustomers = new ArrayList<Bookmark>();

        //get the JSON array of the ordered of sorted customers
        String jsonListOfSortedCustomerId = mSharedPreferences.getString(LIST_OF_SORTED_DATA_ID, "");


        //check for null
        assert jsonListOfSortedCustomerId != null;
        if (!jsonListOfSortedCustomerId.isEmpty()){

            //convert JSON array into a List<Long>
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ArrayList<String> listOfSortedCustomersId = gson.fromJson(jsonListOfSortedCustomerId, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType());

            //build sorted list
            if (listOfSortedCustomersId != null && listOfSortedCustomersId.size() > 0){
                for (String id: listOfSortedCustomersId){
                    for (Bookmark customer: customerList){
                        if (id.equals(customer.getId())){
                            sortedCustomers.add(customer);
                            customerList.remove(customer);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //if there are still customers that were not in the sorted list
            //maybe they were added after the last drag and drop
            //add them to the sorted list
            if (customerList.size() > 0){
                sortedCustomers.addAll(customerList);
            }

            return sortedCustomers;
        }else {
            return customerList;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        buildBookmarkArrayListfromDB();
    }
}
```

`Adapter.class`

```
public class AdapterForBookmark extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public static final int ITEM_TYPE_ONE = 0;
    public static final int ITEM_TYPE_TWO = 1;
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList;
    String BASE_URL = "https://besticon-demo.herokuapp.com/icon?url=";
    private Context context;
    private int lastPosition = -1;
    private Bookmark bookmark;

    public AdapterForBookmark(Context context, ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList, Bookmark bookmark) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.bookmark = bookmark;
    }

    public AdapterForBookmark(Context context, ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = null;
        if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_ONE) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.speed_link_item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);

        } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_TWO) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.not_active_item, parent, false);
            return new TextViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final int itemType = getItemViewType(position);
        final Bookmark bookmark = (Bookmark) this.arrayList.get(position);

        if (itemType == ITEM_TYPE_ONE) {
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;

            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
            ViewHolder.tvName.startAnimation(animation);
            viewHolder.tvMove.startAnimation(animation);
            viewHolder.tvDel.startAnimation(animation);
            viewHolder.tvIcon.startAnimation(animation);
            ViewHolder.tvName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
            lastPosition = position;
            String imageUrl = BASE_URL + arrayList.get(position).getSearchUrl() + "&size=32";
            RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
            int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position).getIcon()), "drawable", context.getPackageName());            // if resID == 0 means the icon is not available in drawable folder
            if (resID == 0) {
                Glide.with(context)
                        .load(imageUrl)
                        .apply(requestOptions
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_favicon)
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                .fitCenter())
                        .into(viewHolder.tvIcon);
            } else {
                viewHolder.tvIcon.setImageResource(resID);
            }

            if (bookmark.getHidden() != null) {
                viewHolder.tvDel.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_move_add);
            } else
                viewHolder.tvDel.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_move_del);

            viewHolder.tvDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    bookmark.setHidden("hidden");
                    arrayList.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            viewHolder.tvName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityChangeBookmark.class);
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    viewHolder.tvIcon.buildDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap image = viewHolder.tvIcon.getDrawingCache();
                    intent.putExtra("selectedNote", arrayList.get(position));
                    extras.putParcelable("Image", image);
                    intent.putExtras(extras);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        } else if (itemType == ITEM_TYPE_TWO) {
            TextViewHolder textViewHolder = (TextViewHolder) holder;
            textViewHolder.textView.setText("Inactive Bookmarks");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // based on you list you will return the ViewType
        if (arrayList.get(position).getViewType() == 0) {

            return ITEM_TYPE_ONE;
        } else {
            return ITEM_TYPE_TWO;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
        holder.itemView.clearAnimation();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private static TextView tvName, tvId, tvSearchUrl, tvNativeUrl;

        ImageView tvIcon, tvMove, tvDel;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSiteTitle);
            tvIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFav);
            tvMove = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivMove);
            tvDel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDel);
            tvDel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvMove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    public class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        public TextViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inactiveBookmark);
        }
    }
```

`SQLite.DB`

```
public class BookmarkDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "bookmarks.db"; // The name of the database file
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;  // The Database version

    public static final String TBL_BOOKMARK = "bookmark";
    public static final String COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID; // equates to _id
    public static final String COl_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COl_HIDDEN = "hidden";
    public static final String COL_ICON = "icon";
    public static final String COL_NATIVEURL = "nativeurl";
    public static final String COL_SEARCHURL = "searchurl";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    Context mContext;

    public BookmarkDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // The SQL to be used to create the table
        String crt_bookmark_tbl_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_BOOKMARK + "(" +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COl_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                COl_HIDDEN + " INTEGER, " +
                COL_ICON + " TEXT, " +
                COL_NATIVEURL + " TEXT," +
                COL_SEARCHURL + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_bookmark_tbl_sql); // CREATE THE TABLE

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + DBNAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void updateName(String newName, int id, String oldName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE " + TBL_BOOKMARK + " SET " + COl_NAME +
                " = '" + newName + "' WHERE " + COL_ID + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + COl_NAME + " = '" + oldName + "'";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    public long addBookmark(long id, String name, boolean hidden, String icon, String nativeurl, String searchurl) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COl_HIDDEN, hidden);
        cv.put(COl_NAME, name);
        cv.put(COL_ICON, icon);
        cv.put(COL_NATIVEURL, nativeurl);
        cv.put(COL_SEARCHURL, searchurl);
        return mDB.insert(TBL_BOOKMARK, null, cv);

        // uses the convenience insert method that builds the SQL
    }

    public ArrayList<Bookmark> getAllBookmarks() {
        ArrayList<Bookmark> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_BOOKMARK, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Bookmark b = new Bookmark();
            b.setId(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ID)));
            int Icon = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ICON));
            String name = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_NAME));
            String searchUrl = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_SEARCHURL));
            b.setIcon(Icon);
            b.setName(name);
            b.setSearchUrl(searchUrl);
            b.setViewType(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_NAME)));
            b.setNativeUrl(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_NATIVEURL)));
            rv.add(b);
        }
        return rv;

    }

    public void deleteBookmark(int id, String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "DELETE FROM " + TBL_BOOKMARK + " WHERE "
                + COL_ID + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + COl_NAME + " = '" + name + "'";

        Log.d("Deleted", "Item" + query);
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    public boolean ifNativeUrlExists(String nativeUrl) {

        boolean rv = false;
        String whereclause = COL_NATIVEURL + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{nativeUrl};
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_BOOKMARK, null, whereclause, whereargs, null, null, null);
        if (csr.getCount() > 0) {
            rv = true;
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public Cursor getItemID(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String query = "SELECT " + COL_ID + " FROM " + TBL_BOOKMARK + " WHERE " +
                COl_NAME + " ='" + name + "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    public void updateOrder(long rowID, int newPos) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_ID, newPos);
        mDB.update(TBL_BOOKMARK, cv, COL_ID + "=" + rowID, null);
    }


}
```

Comment: Hey, is this the one you wanted me to look into?

Comment: This is too much code I think. Can you please just keep the relevant code only? So that it is easier to understand the problem? Also, it would be great if you could make a video of your problem, because the write-up does not says clearly what it is. Thanks.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I will try to make a video of it.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I have added a link, there is the video.